# Populating linked list function not storing data in structure and crashing on print

Tags: c, list, pointers, struct, typedef

So I'm working on a little C program which is a little address book that automatically allocates memory when you add a new contact in it.

I'm using two typedef structures, the first one stores the info on the contact (name telephone etc.):

```
typedef struct
{
    char nom[TAILLE1];
    char tel[TAILLE2];
} CONTACT;
```

The seconde one contains a int with the number of contacts in the address book and an other one is the pointer to the other structure.

```
typedef struct
{
    int nb;
    CONTACT * contacts; // tableau
} LISTE_TABLEAU;
```

I created a function to import contact from a TXT file (first line the name of the person, second line their telephone number and so on). I simplified it with only the basic

```
int lireDonneesTxt(LISTE_TABLEAU* tab)
{
    int i;
    tab->contacts = (CONTACT *)malloc(sizeof(CONTACT)*13); (13 because there are 13 contact for testing purposes)
    i = 0;

    while( !feof(entree) )
    {
        fgets(ligne, TAILLE1, entree);
        strcpy(tab->contacts[i].nom, ligne);

        fgets(ligne, TAILLE1, entree);
        strcpy(tab->contacts[i].tel, ligne);

        i++
    }
    return 1;
}
```

When I compile my code there isn't any issue, no warning what so ever.

But when I run my code everything works great until I try and print a name on the screen, then the executable file crashes.

My main function looks something like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    LISTE_TABLEAU *tabb;
    tabb->nb    = 0;

    lireDonneesTxt(&tabb);

    printf("%s", tabb->contacts[0].nom);

    return 0;
}
```

If I add the same printf that is in the `main` at the end of my `lireDonneesTxt` function it prints the name without any problem. 
I'm guessing that the data is not passed correctly to the structure.

I am now blocked and have no idea what to try to make this work !

Comment: If you're on Linux, use valgrind to troubleshoot your memory access problems.

Comment: [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Comment: `lireDonneesTxt()` - ah bon, vraiment? **No one ever** uses non-English identifiers in one's code...

Comment: @H2CO3 Obviously, "No one ever" is a bit of an overstatement. It may be highly disrecommended, and even uncommon, to use non-English identifiers, but it doesn't take much searching to find counter-examples to that statement...

Comment: @twalberg I meant, "no sane programmer" :)

Answer (score 3):

Don't pass the address of the `LISTE_TABLEAU` pointer here:

```
lireDonneesTxt(&tabb);
```

just pass the pointer

```
lireDonneesTxt(tabb);
```

Also setting `tabb->nb    = 0;` to unalocated memory is undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The memory is not allocated for "tabb" & you are trying to access its member variable (tabb->nb) in main() function. It is illegal, thus the run time crash.

You can try the below code instead:

```
int main(void)
{
    LISTE_TABLEAU tabb;
    tabb.nb    = 0;

    lireDonneesTxt(&tabb);

    printf("%s", tabb.contacts[0].nom);

    return 0;
}
```